# Java paintComponent not being called

Tags: java, swing

For some reason paintComponent is not being called. If the thread isn't spawned it will run once. Why does the thread stop it from running?

```
package com.example.cellcitygame;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/**
 * Manages memory, entities, map, objects, etc.
 * 
 * @author John Smith
 */

public class Scene extends JPanel {
    public ArrayList<Entity> entities = new ArrayList<>();

    Image background;
    Image good;
    Image bad;
    Image digested;
    Image protein1;
    Image protein2;
    Image protein3;
    Image protein4;

    public Scene() {
        background = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("BG.png"))
                .getImage();
        good = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("Good.png"))
                .getImage();
        bad = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("Bad.png")).getImage();
        digested = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("Digested.png"))
                .getImage();
        protein1 = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("Protein1.png"))
                .getImage();
        protein2 = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("Protein2.png"))
                .getImage();
        protein4 = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("Protein4.png"))
                .getImage();
        protein3 = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("Protein3.png"))
                .getImage();

        Entity test = new Entity();
        test.targetX = 500;
        test.targetY = 300;
        test.x = 100;
        test.y = 100;
        entities.add(test);

        new UpdateThread().start();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        for (Entity entity : entities) {
            entity.draw(g);
        }

        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
        g.dispose();
    }

    class UpdateThread extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                for (Entity entity : entities) {
                    entity.update();
                }

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                repaint();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm wondering if it has to do with the update loop being too fast?

TIA

Comment: Neither `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync()` or `g.dispose()` are good ideas.  I'm assuming that you actually added the panel to a top level container and that the panel has a size > 0.  I'm also assuming that the entity is actually begin painted within the visual bounds of the panel...

Comment: There's also no synchronisation around `entities` mean that the thread could be updating them while the `paintComponent` method is trying to paint them, just saying...

Comment: That would be correct. It's seemingly random how sometimes it paints and other times it won't. I have coordinates being debugged to me and they're well within the pane.

Comment: may have to call `revalidate` too after repaint ??

Comment: @nachokk `revalidate` relates to the layout API, best to call this before `repaint` ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer right , always forget the order xD